# More comment shorthand links proposed and auto expand to text

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I find myself typing a lot of redundant comments, especially for new visitors to the site.

I know we have [comment shorthand links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for common help articles, but I am suggesting a way in which I could type a quick moniker - and it auto-expand to something with more text and perhaps a link as well.

Here's a sample list of things I find myself typing often:

1. Welcome to Stack Overflow.
2. Please share your actual code, within a code block, in your question.
3. Do not post pictures or screenshots of your code, paste the source
   code out directly within a code block.
4. This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166177). What are you really trying to do?
5. If you found this answer helpful, don't forget to upvote and/or
   accept it.
6. I updated my answer.
7. Not a programming question. Belongs on Super User.
8. Not a programming question. Belongs on Server Fault.

It would be nice to just type shorthand into the comment block, `[welcome]` or `[xyproblem]` and it auto expand to one of the comments above.

Comment: 5, 7 and 8 should never be posted. In general: Interesting proposal.

Comment: Yeah, #5 might as well expand to "Would you please DV my answer". Just saying.

Comment: I'm ok with number 5. I only use that comment for new visitors with their first question.  I'm sometimes the only person who answers - sometimes with a lot of detail.  I spent 10-15 minutes writing the answer.  They comment back with, "Thanks, that was what I needed".  So what I really mean to say `Hey Newbie, this guy basically just did your CS 101 homework for you. Please give him due credit`. I don't think I'm asking for too much. Tag could be `[showmethemoney]`

Comment: You do know [auto review comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)? In SOCVR we have a repository with comments to use: https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments

Comment: "This sounds like an XY problem..." is a horrible comment. If someone is asking a question and that question is on-topic and answerable, answer it or move on. If they asked the wrong question ,let them figure that out. So many reasonable on-topic questions get derailed by such nonsense comments.

Comment: @TinyGiant While answering the question *as stated* is always helpful, pointing out a *better way of structuring things* so that a convoluted approach isn't required is probably even better. If something can be properly identified as an X/Y problem, and the proper Y solution can be explained, that has much more value to the site IMO. I think prodding the OP to see if there's a good reason why they're doing things the way they are can have benefits. It may not pan out, but I don't see the harm in trying, as long as the comment is kind

Comment: @CertainPerformance I absolutely disagree. I hate arriving at a question from google only to find an answer that explains an entirely different solution to an entirely different problem. It's as useful as not having an answer at all.

Comment: [It is ***not*** *StackOverflow*, *SuperUser*, and *ServerFault*](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (see the last section). It is ***Stack Overflow***, ***Super User***, and ***Server Fault***, respectively.

Comment: @TinyGiant Consider questions like *How do fix my regex to parse <complicated HTML structure>* (don't, use an HTML parser instead for non-trivial cases) or *How do I select all elements with the same ID in HTML* (that's invalid HTML, change it to use classes instead) or *How do I fix my for loop so that it `splice`s the desired index when removing elements from an array* (use `Array.prototype.filter` instead). These are all pretty straightforward X/Y problems - I think that ignoring the *possibility* that the (much more elegant) Y solution is applicable is doing a disservice to future readers.